# How to choose self-loops in MCMC proposal chain?

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo

In the Metropolis Hastings version of Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) I believe that the proposal chain can have self-loops, and those self loops will always lead to transitions that will be accepted.  Is that right? If so, are there any recommendations about how to set the self-loops? My feeling is that given that self-loops are always accepted, their impact on convergence is huge.

More details: $$
  a(i,j) = \frac{\pi_j T_{ji}}{\pi_i T_{ij}} $$

If we have a self loop in the proposal chain, $\pi_i=\pi_j$ and $T_{ji} = T_{ij}$ therefore, $a(i,j)=1$ so the self-loops will be always accepted. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Self-loops are accepted, but are exceedingly unlikely if the proposal distribution is chosen well. For a loop to have non-negligible effects on asymptotic convergence, it would require getting the same samples from the proposal distribution at the same points in the loop infinitely often. This is obviously not the case for most standard choices of proposal distribution.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Please, may you elaborate a bit more? If the target distribution puts a lot of mass in a given state, isn't it natural that adding a self loop at that state will improve convergence speed?

Comment: I don't see self-loops as something that improve convergence speed. It is typically considered detrimental for MCMC chains to have high autocorrelation. Biasing the chain in some way to stay in regions of high posterior density can be detrimental in cases where the state space is high dimensional and a significant amount of the probability mass is located in regions far from high probability density. This is what many state-of-the-art MCMC algorithms aim to avoid, like No U-turn Sampling